# java: variable not known in current context? loss of value when opening new JFrame and calling child class

Tags: java, variables

Basically, I have a collection which is public in main class, and when I call child class, collection size becomes 0 and while debugging, it says that variable not known in current context, what could be the issue? It is a coursework so I don't really want to paste the code, but if required, I will give more explanation. Thank you.

Comment: have you initialized all local variables before using them?

Comment: I think I have, is there any way to check? (I am using A LOT of variables, which makes it hard to check). Also, could the problem be because I am trying to use that collection in child class for a loop?

Comment: whatever line is giving you the "variable not known in current context" error should point towards where the issue is.  I would check any local variables that are used where the compile error occurs.

Comment: @Zack Macomber Basically, collection becomes not known only when new JFrame is opened by calling it from main class. I call the new JFrame like this:
<pre><code>Checkout.main(null)

Comment: Make sure that collection is initialized, even if it's just initialized to null.  If you post the applicable code snippets where the issue is happening, more people might be able to chime in on where the problem is.

Comment: OK, I don't know how to put code inline, so I will simply paste it with explanation.

I have PurchaseItem class, where is the original Collection of data, while debugging, collection size doesn't change up until this line:

> Checkout.main(null); <

Then when it opens Checkout JFrame first thing it does when you press proceed button is this, and that is where collection becomes unknown variable:

> PurchaseItem purchaseitem = new PurchaseItem(); <
> purchaseitem.deleteStock(); < 

deleteStock() method contains the loop where I need collection size... I hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by changing collection to static, that helped me when calling a method from JFrame as I didn't need to make a new instance, I think making new instance caused the collection to become unknown.